# WMTS multidimensional nodata

Tags: geoserver

We have a coverage view layer for an imagemosaic store and we are trying to figure out a way to get available dates, that are inside a bounding box, from the said layer. A wmts GetDomainValues request gives us the time results but they also include dates where the bounding box entirely consists of nodata values. Is there a way to filter these results so we can get a list of available dates with actual visual data in them?

Comment: I don't think there is any way for GeoServer to distinguish between a full image and an empty one

Comment: Thank you Ian for your tepki. We have to implement in our backside with wmts and footprints of the images.